# I am getting wrong assets url using Laravel helper "secure_asset"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a website on domain mydomain.space

I include in my blade file some js file in such way:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="{!! secure_asset('js/app.js') !!}"></script>
```

But then, on production, I see in browser logs, that frontend try to load file by this URL:

```
http://mydomainspace/js/app.js
```

Yeah, for some reason it removes dot and as result - it is wrong URL...
But when I display APP_URL variable - it shows "mydomain.space" (with dot).

Why I lose dot in URL when use secure_asset helper?

Comment: `APP_URL` isn't used for generating URLs when a request comes in through the web. The request has the host information from the server and that is used

Answer (score 0):

I would try using mix instead:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

It provides a lot of benefits and may resolve your issue https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix

That being said I would ensure your APP_URL is not being changed in the app.php file

Answer (score 0):

Setting ASSET_URL in .env was a fix for me:

```
ASSET_URL=http://localhost
```